# Using route() and with() in html view in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

For redirection, in controllers, we can write like this:-

```
Redirect::Route('front_index')->with('RegError', 'An error occured while adding the user.');
```

How can I set up the `href` of an anchor tag so that I can send the 'RegError' too? Say something like this?

```
<a href="{{route('front_index')->with('RegError', '')}}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you can't because `with` function is used to pass parameters from controllers to view and `route` helper doesn't have this method.
You need to make request and in controller pass your `RegError`